# On iPad or iPhone, how to progress PDF with "Fade" or "Appear" instead of slide-in from right?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, preview

The pages of my pdf presentation add incremental changes to the first page. The second page, for instance, consists of the diagram on the first page in addition to a few more lines. This way a complex figure can be introduced gradually.

But whether the PDF is viewed in iOS' inbuilt files viewer, or other apps like Google Drive, Amazon Kindle, etc, the PDF always "slides in" each page, which defeats the effect I am after (a few changes just appear). Instead the audience is treated to a distracting effect.

Is there a way to disable the sliding and go back to replacing pages? Or any app that shows slides with just a simple "Appear" kind of effect? Welcome any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try a presentation app like Keynote or even Prezi for slick presentations. Do you _need_ to use the PDF file?

Comment: Yes, PDF format is a must as it needs to be shared.

Comment: You could use the PDF as a starting point for the Keynote or Prezi presentations, and still have the PDF to distribute.

Comment: Thank you. But keynote on my phone doesn’t seem to be able to open PDF files. They are in Files (saved from google drive), but keynote lists them greyed out. Any ideas?